# Getting the current folder path when trying to get ProgramFilesX86 on server 2003

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server

When I'm trying to call this method from windows server 2003 SP2 Enterprise Edition KN x86:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
```

I am getting the current directory rather than the program files directory, for example, my application is installed in this location:
C:\Program Files\Company\ApplocationName\SomeApp.exe

When calling:

```
string x = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
```

x value will be: C:\Program Files\Company\ApplocationName

Is it a known issue? is there any ideas about this?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, You are saying "for example, my application is installed in this location: C:\Program Files\Company\ApplocationName\SomeApp.exe" and you are getting "C:\Program Files\Company\ApplocationName" so what is the issue ?

Comment: What do you have in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir(x86)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

> "On an x86 system, passing the ProgramFilesX86 member to the Environment.GetFolderPath method returns String.Empty; use the ProgramFiles member instead. You can determine whether Windows is a 32-bit operating system by calling the Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem property."

So you should use

```
string x = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

Comment: Here is the MSDN article link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx